# Как вместить текст в одну строку

Tags: css, css3

Необходимо вместить название в одну строку. В разметке есть блок див фиксированного размера. Необходимо применить какой то ксс, который вместит текст в одну строку, что бы небыло переноса и текст был видим. Я представляю для себя только один метод реализации, в ксс должен установиться такой размер шрифта, при котором как раз текст не будет вылазить.

Вот сайт над которым я работаю: [Сайт](http://onedaytv.ru/project.php?id=3)

Здесь есть надпись "Максим+Анастасия". Именно этот элемент необходимо вместить в одну строку. И да, если текст помещается при текущем размере шрифта то размер его изменять не нужно.

Comment: все правильно представляете, только на одном css этого не сделать. js или +jquery - да

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev там возможно обойтись без js, потому что размер блока, как указано в вопросе - фиксированный, следовательно, не надо вычислять динамически размер шрифта, нужно просто подобрать размер. Добавить класс для тега, и укажите ему свойство font-size с нужным размером.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, размер блока фиксированный, а вот текст я так понял разный.

Comment: Да текст постоянно разный

Comment: Используйте css класс white-space со значением nowrap https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так на чистом js можно

```js
var title = document.getElementById('title');
var fontSize = 30;
while(title.offsetHeight > 30){
  fontSize--;
  title.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
}
```

```css
#title { line-height: 30px; font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; width: 200px; }
```

```html
<h3 id="title">Максим + Анастасия</h3>
```

Comment: Попробуйте пожалуйста вновь зайти на сайт. я установил Ваш вариант, но кажется что то не в порядке, так как шрифт достаточно сильно уменьшился)

Comment: @iSeeDev, вижу что идеально встает по ширине, сильно уменьшился - да, но тут уж ширины не хватает.

Comment: Кажется я не доглядел. Уменьшение приемлемое. Спасибо за решение!